# Store bids in microtime

Tags: php, codeigniter

How would you store bids according to the local time of the server in php codeigniter?
so every time the user enters a bid , the php would use a microtime function to store it?

function create($user_bid){

```
    $this->db->set('bid', $user_bid);
    $this->db->set('microtime'=>microtime(TRUE)));
    $this->db->insert('products',array('microtime'=>microtime(true)));


    $query= $this->db->insert('products');


    $this->load->view('bidding');
```

}
}

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Which part are you asking about? How to generate the microtime value or how to store it? Either way, it's apparent you have not researched the question yourself.

Comment: i have tried the code above, its inserting the bids but no time on the bids. i want it to store the time of the bids

Comment: What is the data type for the column? Also, why are you setting the value twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a MySQL database, why not simply have a TIMESTAMP column on your database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html and leave MySQL to populate it for you

Comment: thank you, is there any chance you can store it in milliseconds

Comment: MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 $bidTime = microtime(true);
 $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `bids` SET `microtime` = ?, [...]")
 ->execute(array( $bidTime, [...]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the syntax for CodeIgniter to insert

```
$this->db->insert('bids',array('microtime'=>microtime(true)));
```

Comment: how would i link it to a bid that i am storing in a database,

Comment: you can use $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('bids',array('microtime'=>microtime(true)); where $id is the id you are updating